# How to remove duplicate from array with nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which have region and location in it. Location is another object in the array.
For Example:

```
let arr= [{"regionId":1,"regionName:"xyz","location":{"locationId":1,"locationName":"abc"}}]
```

In above example region can have multiple entries but for a particular region, can have only different location.

Example:

```
let arr= [{"regionId":1,"regionName:"xyz","location":{"locationId":1,"locationName":"abc"}},
          {"regionId":1,"regionName:"xyz","location":{"locationId":1,"locationName":"def"}}, 
          {"regionId":1,"regionName:"xyz","location":{"locationId":1,"locationName":"ghi"}}]
```

But cannot have same location with with same region.

```
let arr= [{"regionId":1,"regionName:"xyz","location":{"locationId":1,"locationName":"abc"}},
          {"regionId":1,"regionName:"xyz","location":{"locationId":1,"locationName":"abc"}} 
          ]
```

So how to avoid above case. How to remove those entries from array.
By the way below case is acceptable.

```
let arr= [{"regionId":1,"regionName:"xyz","location":{"locationId":1,"locationName":"abc"}},
          {"regionId":2,"regionName:"mno","location":{"locationId":1,"locationName":"abc"}} 
          ]
```

Comment: Post  JavaScript code as a [mcve] like functions, methods, etc., not just arrays. It looks like you are asking others to do your coding.

Answer (score 0):

you can use array.reduce.. something like this:

```js
 let arr= [
      {regionId:1,regionName:"xyz",location:{locationId:1,locationName:"abc"}},
      {regionId:1,regionName:"xyz",location:{locationId:1,locationName:"def"}}, 
      {regionId:1,regionName:"xyz",location:{locationId:1,locationName:"ghi"}},
      {regionId:1,regionName:"xyz",location:{locationId:1,locationName:"abc"}},
      {regionId:1,regionName:"mno",location:{locationId:1,locationName:"abc"}}
    ];
    
    
    const reducedArr = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
      if(acc.length === 0) {
        acc.push(cur);
      }
    
      if(acc.findIndex((el) => el.regionName === cur.regionName && el.location.locationName === cur.location.locationName) > -1) {
        return acc;  
      }
      acc.push(cur);
      return acc;
    }, []);
    
    console.log(reducedArr);
```